# Kentucky Derby vs. Royal Ascot vs. Dubai World Cup

Tags: horse-racing

What's the relationship between the Kentucky Derby and the Royal Ascot horse races? The Dubai World Cup? Although [some horses do, over the course of their careers, compete in all three](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/04/02/sport/horse-racing-california-chrome-ascot/index.html), it seems rare compared to competing for the US triple crown. Is one event higher priority (perhaps more prestigious) for owners than the other two? Does one breed a different type of horse for the Derby than the Ascot (say, due to different surfaces)?